# PDO insert not working error message

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to figure out why this wont work I had it working with adding just one entry off of the form and then added email and it broke it. Also is this safe from SQL Injection? Here is the error message

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

Here is my code for insert.php:

```
<?php 

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=info', 'blah', 'test');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO people (name, email) VALUES (:name, :email)');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $POST_['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
#If one or more rows were returned...

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Here is the working code if I am inserting only one value from the form:

```
<?php 

try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=encorem2_info', 'encorem2', 'Yamaha!32088!');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES (:name)');

$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));

#If one or more rows were returned...

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Here is my html code in separate file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome!</title>

    </head>
    <body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the bindParams

Comment: Same thing I have been trying several different methods but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind both params when you execute and skip the separate `bindParam()` calls.

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $POST_['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
```

should just be

```
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':email' => $_POST['email']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no reason to pass anything to execute when you have already bound the parameters individually.  Just call

```
$stmt->execute();
```

After your bindParam calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your data in either the [`bindParam`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) OR [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).  It'd be simpler to replace

```
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $POST_['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name']));
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
```

with

```
$stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'],':email' => $_POST['email']));
```